# How to pivot row's unique values and mark its occurrence?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, data-science

I'm looking for a solution for the case bellow:

1. How do I pivot df such that the col values become columns when df consist only one dimension?
2. And how to proceed in order to have in a result in each column made from those rows value 0 or 1 depending on occurrences for each of them in the previous column?

It'll be easier to illustrate it.
So from this kind of data frame:

```
df =

DATA   
cat1
dog1
cat2
dog2
cat3
dog3
...
```

to this kind of data frame:

```
df =

Animal   cat1   dog1   cat2   dog2   cat3   dog3    ...
cat1    1      0      0      0      0      0        ...
dog1    0      1      0      0      0      0        ...
cat2    0      0      1      0      0      0        ...
dog2    0      0      0      1      0      0        ...
cat3    0      0      0      0      1      0        ...
dog3    0      0      0      0      0      1        ...
...   
cat1    1      0      0      0      0      0        ...
dog1    0      1      0      0      0      0        ...
```

First I've tried to gather all unique values and then I reshaped it to `pd.DataFrame` because it was a np array. Then I've tried to use pivot. I know that it should have arguments like 'index', 'column' and 'values', but in my case, I have only one dimension (just one column).

```
to_reschape = df.Animal.unique()
type(to_reschape)
dataset = pd.DataFrame(to_reschape)
dataset.pivot()

KeyError: None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command:

Where df,

```
   DATA
0  cat1
1  dog1
2  cat2
3  dog2
4  cat3
5  dog3
6  dog1
```

Use,

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(df.DATA), prefix='', prefix_sep='')
```

Output:

```
      cat1  cat2  cat3  dog1  dog2  dog3
DATA                                    
cat1     1     0     0     0     0     0
dog1     0     0     0     1     0     0
cat2     0     1     0     0     0     0
dog2     0     0     0     0     1     0
cat3     0     0     1     0     0     0
dog3     0     0     0     0     0     1
dog1     0     0     0     1     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Scott, it was very helpfull! Frankly speaking, I didn't know get_dummies.